# A compact embedding claim

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, hilbert-spaces, compactness

Let $U= (0,1)\times (0,1)$. Consider the weighted Sobolev spaces $H_1$ with the norms
$$ \|u\|_{H_1}^2 = \int_0^1 (\int_0^1 x\,|u(x,y)|^2\,dx) \,dy$$
Let $H_2$ be the weighted Sobolev space with the norm
$$ \|u\|_{H_2}^2= \int_0^1 (\int_0^1 x^2(|\partial_x u(x,y)|^2+|\partial_y u(x,y)|^2)\,dx) \,dy+ \int_0^1 (\int_0^1 x\,|u(x,y)|^2\,dx) \,dy$$
subject to the additional constraint that $u(x,1)=u(x,0)=u(1,y)=0$ for all $x,y \in (0,1)$.

Is the embedding $H_2 \subset H_1$ compact?

Comment: In "Sharp Conditions for Weighted 1-dimensional Poincaré Inequalities" https://www.jstor.org/stable/24901034 , they go over comparison inequalities between u and its derivative but with different weights as in your case, which might be useful.  They have a 2d version too in Theorem 3.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $\|u\|_{H^2} \leq 1$ and by H"older
$$|u(x,y)|\leq \int_x^1 |u_x(t,y)|\, dt \leq \left (\int_x^1 t^2 u_x^2(t,y)\, dt\right )^{\frac 12}\left (\int_x^1 \frac{1}{t^2}\right )^{\frac 12} \leq \frac{C}{\sqrt x}
$$
$C= \sqrt 2$, for example. Given $\delta$ we have,
$$
\int_0^{\delta^2}  \int_0^1 xu^2(x,y)dx dy \leq C\delta^2.
$$
Since in $Q_\delta=[\delta^2,1]\times [0,1]$ the norms in $H_1, H_2$ are equivalent to those of $L^2, W^{1,2}$, by the compactness of Sobolev embeddng we can cover the unit ball of $H_2(Q_\delta)$ with a finite number of $\delta$-balls in $H_1(Q_\delta)$ and the same balls give a finite covering (with a slightly changed $\delta$) of the unit ball of $H_2$.

Comment: thanks a lot for your clear proof. Could you make a comment about what happens if no vanishing condition is imposed in the definition of the H_2 space? In that case compactness claim would not hold, right?

Comment: The result still holds. Just use a cut-off v in x to split $u=vu+(1-v)u$. If v vanishes near zero, $uv$ does not see the singularity and the previous argument applies to $(1-v)u$.